# Obtaining Laurent series at $z=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following

Problem Obtain the Laurent Series for $g(z)=\frac{z-2}{z+1}$ centered at $z=-1$ and specify the domain of convergence.

My idea was to manipulate $g(z)$ in a way to be able to use geometric series because that usually gives me the interval of convergence and the series.

$$g(z)= \frac{z-2}{z+1} =\frac{z+1-3}{z+1}= 1- \frac{3}{z+1}=1-3 \sum_0 ^\infty (-1)^n(z)^n$$

for $|z|<1$ and I can do something similar for $|z|>1$, my problem is that I am confused. I taught that the Laurent series should be $\sum a_n (z-z_0)^n$ and $z_0$ is the point of expansion this what I obtained is not the series centered at $-1$ but at zero. Can someone guide me how to do this properly ?

Comment: I cannot edit you post for so few so here are my suggestions for improvement(s) :  [Laurant]--->[Laurent] and [I taught that the Laurent series]--->[I learned that the Laurent series]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\displaystyle\frac{z-2}{z+1}=\frac{z+1-3}{z+1}=\frac{-3}{z+1}+1$. If you want your Laurent series to be centered at $-1$, this is exactly it; here, $$a_{-1}=-3,\quad a_0=1,\quad a_n=0\,\,\forall n\neq -1,0.$$

Comment: Isn't this what I wrote?

Comment: You are right; I'll write more.

Comment: Just about to write the same thing (+1)

Comment: Sorry, I know it should be obvious, but I do not see how you get the a's or how we obtain the radius of convergence.

Comment: I see it now thank you so much!